# MonoTouch Hello World for iPad

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have tried following the sample Hello World for MonoTouch by creating an iPad solution. For some reason I cannot get the MainWindow to load. I followed the instructions exactly and the app just closes before even loading a view. Is there something missing? Do I need to tell the solution how to load the MainWindow.XIB or something? Please help, this seems very basic and I am about to throw MonoTouch in the garbage.

Answer (score 0):

What example are you trying to follow? By default a new iPad solution in MonoDevelop should give you a working (empty) app which will load your MainWindow.xib on startup.

Answer (score 0):

http://monotouch.net/ipad

Hope this helps

Alex

Answer (score -1):

Did you obey the installation order? Base SDK, Mono, Monotouch, Monodevelop?

René

Answer (score -2):

Thats what I was trying, just a blank iPad project to begin. Still no luck, I guess tonight I will try to reinstall the whole IDE....running out of ideas here...